# show the popped element in c++?

Tags: c++

I have problem at the last part of this program. How can I display the element that have been popped?

I try to change the looping, but cannot..

```
#include<iostream.h>
typedef struct TINDANAN
{
    int atas;
    char senarai[4];
} tindanan;

void cipta(tindanan *t);
void push(tindanan *t);
void pop(tindanan *t);
int penuh(tindanan *t);
int kosong(tindanan *t);

void main()
{
    int pilihan,jawapan,i;
    tindanan t;
    cipta(&t);
    cout<<"\n1->Push\t\n 2->Pop \t\n 3-> Keluar \n pilihan =";
    cin>>pilihan;
    while(pilihan !=3)
    {
        switch (pilihan)
        {
            case 1: push(&t);
                break;
            case 2: pop(&t);
                break;
            default : cout<<"\nTidak Sah";
        }
        cout<<"\n1->Push\t\n 2->Pop \t\n 3-> Keluar \n pilihan =";
        cin>>pilihan;
    }
}

void cipta (tindanan *t)
{
    t->atas =-1;
}

int penuh (tindanan *t)
{
    if (t->atas ==3)
        return (1);
    else
        return (0);
}

void push (tindanan *t)
{
    int i;
    char data;
    if (penuh(t) ==1)
        cout<<"\nTindanan Penuh\n";
    else
    {
        cout<<"\nHuruf Character: ";
        cin>>data;
        t->atas++;
        t->senarai[t->atas]=data;
        cout<<"\nKandungan Timbunan :\nIndex | Data\n";
        for(i=t->atas;i>-1;i--)
            cout<<"| "<<i<< " | "<< t->senarai[i];
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}

int kosong (tindanan *t)
{
    if (t->atas ==-1)
        return (1);
    else
        return (0);
}

void pop (tindanan *t)
{
    int i;
    if(kosong(t) == 1)
        cout<<"\nTindanan Kosong\n";
    else
    {
        t->atas--;
        cout<<"\nkandungan Timbunan :\nIndex | data\n";
        for(i=t->atas;i>-1;i--)
            cout<<" | "<<i<< " | "<<( t->senarai[i]);
        cout<<"\nPop Item";
        for(i=3;i>t->atas;i--)
            cout<<"| "<<i<< " | "<< t->senarai[i];
    }
}
```

Sorry I'm just learn c++ this year.

Comment: Translating it to english would be a nice first step.

Comment: You may get more answers if you fix your code formatting. Add tabs and such. Have not seen `<iostream.h>` used in a while either!

Comment: Do you want to show each itme that gets popped ?

Comment: Apart from the usage of `cout`, this doesn't look like a nice `C++` solution. Get another book or teacher.

Comment: ya, show each time element have been popped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you were trying to do with your second loop in the pop function but this modified pop should display the popped value as well as the existing contents.

```
void pop (tindanan *t)
{
  int i;
  if(kosong(t) == 1)
    cout<<"\nTindanan Kosong\n";
  else
  {
    cout<<"\nPop Item: " << (t->senarai[t->atas]);

    t->atas--;

    cout<<"\nkandungan Timbunan :\nIndex | data\n";
    for(i = t->atas; i > -1; i--)
      cout<<" | "<<i<< " | "<<( t->senarai[i]);
  }
}
```

But in general it would make sense to have pop return the item since that is how things commonly work.  But then again push generally takes the item to push as well.

Alternatively you could write the pop like this and it would return the popped item then you could display it however you want.

```
char pop (tindanan *t)
{
  char popped_item = -1;
  int i;
  if(kosong(t) == 1)
    cout<<"\nTindanan Kosong\n";
  else
  {
    cout<<"\nPop Item: " << (t->senarai[t->atas]);

    popped_item = t->senarai[t->atas];

    t->atas--;

    cout<<"\nkandungan Timbunan :\nIndex | data\n";
    for(i = t->atas; i > -1; i--)
      cout<<" | "<<i<< " | "<<( t->senarai[i]);
  }
  return popped_item;
}
```

Comment: how to show the value have been popped ? or deleted.

Comment: Before you decrement atas (t->atas--) this (t->senarai[t->atas]) is the value popped.  So print that out however you want or return it from the function.

Answer (score 0):

Make pop return a value and make this value equal to the element you are popping(seems to me this is the value you print).